# How to split a string by ignoring commas c#?

Tags: c#, .net, split

I have made a little project that takes .cs files, reads them and returns the most frequent word in the file. However, right now it returns that the most common word is a comma.
How can i make it so splitting the string ignores commas?

For example: i have a string:

> , . ? a a, b cdef cfed, abef abef abef,

right now it returns that the most common word is 'abef' and it occured 2 times (the program doesn't count the third abef, the one which is with a comma in the end.)

Another example:

> , . ? a a, b cdef cfed, abef abef abef, , ,

this right now returns that the most common word is a comma ',' and it occured 3 times, but the thing is - i want my program to ignore commas and focus purely on words only.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp8
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Text Documents |*.cs;*.txt", ValidateNames = true, Multiselect = false }) //openfiledialog (all .cs; all.txt)
        {
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) //if in file dialog a file gets selected
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ofd.FileName)) //text reader
                {
                    richTextBox1.Text = await sr.ReadToEndAsync(); //reads the file and returns it into textbox
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        string[] userText = richTextBox1.Text.ToLower().Split( ' ' );
        var frequencies = new Dictionary<string, int>(); // variable frequencies, dictionary with key string, value int.
        string highestWord = null;  //declare string highestword with starting value null.
        int highestFreq = 0; //declare integer highestfreq with starting value zero.

        foreach (string word in userText) //search words in our array userText that we declared at the beginning.
        {
            int freq; //declare integer freq.
            frequencies.TryGetValue(word, out freq); //trygetvalue from dictionary key, out value.
            freq += 1; //count it.

            if (freq > highestFreq) 
            {
                highestFreq = freq;
                highestWord = word;
            }
            frequencies[word] = freq; //assign most frequent word in frequencies dictionary to freq
        }
        MessageBox.Show("the most occuring word is: " + highestWord + ", it occured " + highestFreq + " times"); //display data to messagebox.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us your code.  Depending on how you're doing this, this could be 1 line of code or 5.

Comment: sorry, code is now added

Comment: FYI, comments like "//declare string highestword with starting value null." don't provide any value whatsoever.  It's obvious from the code next to it that you're declaring a variable with a null value.  Such comments are just clutter.

Comment: Split can take an array of chars to split on. So you can split on space and comma. Then remove the empty entries with the appropriate StringSplitOption

Comment: Adding to what steve said `var words = text.Split(new char[] { ' ', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: I would think you would want to remove all punctuation except maybe special handling for hyphens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Split can take an array of chars to split on. So you can split on space and comma. Then remove the empty entries with the appropriate StringSplitOption

```
 string[] userText = richTextBox1.Text.ToLower().Split(new char[] { ' ', ','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );
```

Also you can use Linq to calculate the frequency of a word with code like this

```
var g = userText.GroupBy(x => x)
                .Select(z => new 
                { word = z.Key, count = z.Count()})
                .ToList();
string mostUsed = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.count)
                   .Select(x => x.word)
                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, however i stumbled upon problem, lets say the space and comma is not the only things i want to remove - i wanna also remove all the curly brackets and dots and equal signs - when i do that, `string[] userText = richTextBox1.Text.ToLower().Split(new char[] { ' ', ',','=','+','}','{' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` it starts taking commas again as the most frequent word in a string , am i missing something?

Comment: Can you give an example string that produces the problem?

Comment: Nevermind, it was just the comma from my textbox! However, it still returns that something invisible is the most common word, no idea what it is? String i am using is from .cs file so i will use pastebin, since there is a character limit in comment section: https://pastebin.com/mVH3CEYb (it says that the most used word is <blank> and it occured 6 times in this string.

Comment: Add a \r and a \n characters to the string to split.

Comment: Works like a charm now! thank you! those were new line characters?(they occur when you press enter) i assume.

Comment: Yes newlines. But using the two char that compose a newline in Windows system individually. Otherwise there is Environment.NewLine but not sure if that will catch the chars correctly if the file is built on a different Operating System

Answer (score 3):

You could replace the commas with an empty string, then run the output through your algorithm.

```
string original = ", . ? a a, b cdef cfed, abef abef abef,";
string noCommas = original.Replace(",", string.Empty);
```

Reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to make the splitting easier to extend by using regular expressions, [Regex.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) more specifically:

```
  string input = ", . ? a a, b cdef cfed, abef abef abef, , ,";
  string[] result = Regex.Split(input, @"\w+");
```

Check [live testing](https://regex101.com/r/YbpCTi/1) here.

If `?` is a valid word, than the regex could be `@"\w+|\?"`.

So, my recommendation is to use regex, even if the split method is enough for now, since it is more powerful and can easily accommodate for later changes.

As a bonus, it is nice to learn about regular expressions.